# How to recover in eclipse a deleted xml validator error marker

Tags: xml, eclipse, dtd

I was writing a DTD file and while validating my xml file against it I was getting a stupid error "Description tag is missing", however the Description tag was in DTD. Even if I was deleting the tag I was getting the same error. So I right clicked the error line in the problems tab and deleted it. Now whenever I click validate any other xml file it shows no errors. How can I recover the deleted marker.

Please help me.
Thanks

MY DTD if it makes sence

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!ELEMENT Course_Catalog (Department*)>
<!ELEMENT Department (Title, Chair, Course*)>
<!ATTLIST Department Code CDATA #REQUIRED> 
<!ELEMENT Title (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT Chair (Professor)> 
<!ELEMENT Professor (First_Name,Middle_Initial?, Last_Name)>  
<!ELEMENT First_Name (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT Middle_Initial (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT Last_Name (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT Course (Title*, Description*, Instructors*, Prerequisites*)>
<!ATTLIST Course    Number CDATA #IMPLIED 
                Enrollment CDATA #IMPLIED>
<!ELEMENT Description (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT Instructors (Lecturer*, Professor*)*>
<!ELEMENT Lecturer (First_Name, Middle_Initial?, Last_Name)>
<!ELEMENT Prerequisites (Prereq*)>
<!ELEMENT Prereq (#PCDATA)>
```

and here comes my XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<!DOCTYPE Q1_1 SYSTEM "Q1_1.dtd">
<Course_Catalog>

  <Department Code="CS">

    <Title>Computer Science</Title>
     <Chair>
      <Professor>
        <First_Name>Jennifer</First_Name>
        <Last_Name>Widom</Last_Name>
      </Professor>
    </Chair>

    <Course Number="CS106A" Enrollment="1070">
      <Title>Programming Methodology</Title>
      <Description>Introduction to the engineering of computer applications emphasizing modern software engineering principles.</Description>
      <Instructors>
        <Lecturer>
          <First_Name>Jerry</First_Name>
          <Middle_Initial>R.</Middle_Initial>
          <Last_Name>Cain</Last_Name>
        </Lecturer>
        <Professor>
          <First_Name>Eric</First_Name>
          <Last_Name>Roberts</Last_Name>
        </Professor>
        <Professor>
          <First_Name>Mehran</First_Name>
          <Last_Name>Sahami</Last_Name>
        </Professor>
      </Instructors>
    </Course>

    <Course Number="CS106B" Enrollment="620">
      <Title>Programming Abstractions</Title>
      <Description>Abstraction and its relation to programming.</Description>
      <Instructors>
        <Professor>
          <First_Name>Eric</First_Name>
          <Last_Name>Roberts</Last_Name>
        </Professor>
        <Lecturer>
          <First_Name>Jerry</First_Name>
          <Middle_Initial>R.</Middle_Initial>
          <Last_Name>Cain</Last_Name>
        </Lecturer>
      </Instructors>
      <Prerequisites>
        <Prereq>CS106A</Prereq>
      </Prerequisites>
    </Course>

    <Course Number="CS107" Enrollment="500">
      <Title>Computer Organization and Systems</Title>
      <Description>Introduction to the fundamental concepts of computer systems.</Description>
      <Instructors>
        <Lecturer>
          <First_Name>Julie</First_Name>
          <Last_Name>Zelenski</Last_Name>
        </Lecturer>
      </Instructors>
      <Prerequisites>
        <Prereq>CS106B</Prereq>
      </Prerequisites>
    </Course>    

    <Course Number="CS109" Enrollment="280">
      <Title>Introduction to Probability for Computer Scientists</Title>
      <Instructors>
        <Professor>
          <First_Name>Mehran</First_Name>
          <Last_Name>Sahami</Last_Name>
        </Professor>
      </Instructors>
      <Prerequisites>
        <Prereq>CS106B</Prereq>
      </Prerequisites>      
    </Course>

    <Course Number="CS124" Enrollment="60">
      <Title>From Languages to Information</Title>
      <Description>Natural language processing. Cross-listed as LING180.</Description>
      <Instructors>
        <Professor>
          <First_Name>Dan</First_Name>
          <Last_Name>Jurafsky</Last_Name>    
        </Professor>
      </Instructors>
      <Prerequisites>
        <Prereq>CS107</Prereq>
        <Prereq>CS109</Prereq>
      </Prerequisites>   
    </Course>

    <Course Number="CS143" Enrollment="90">
      <Title>Compilers</Title>
      <Description>Principles and practices for design and implementation of compilers and interpreters.</Description>
      <Instructors>
        <Professor>
          <First_Name>Alex</First_Name>
          <Middle_Initial>S.</Middle_Initial>
          <Last_Name>Aiken</Last_Name>    
        </Professor>
      </Instructors>
      <Prerequisites>
        <Prereq>CS107</Prereq>
      </Prerequisites>   
    </Course>

    <Course Number="CS145" Enrollment="130">
      <Title>Introduction to Databases</Title>
      <Description>Database design and use of database management systems for applications.</Description>
      <Instructors>
        <Professor>
          <First_Name>Jennifer</First_Name>
          <Last_Name>Widom</Last_Name>    
        </Professor>
      </Instructors>
      <Prerequisites>
        <Prereq>CS107</Prereq>
      </Prerequisites>  
    </Course>

    <Course Number="CS221" Enrollment="180">
      <Title>Artificial Intelligence: Principles and Techniques</Title>
      <Instructors>
        <Professor>
          <First_Name>Andrew</First_Name>
          <Last_Name>Ng</Last_Name>    
        </Professor>
        <Professor>
          <First_Name>Sebastian</First_Name>
          <Last_Name>Thrun</Last_Name>    
        </Professor>        
      </Instructors>
    </Course>

    <Course Number="CS228" Enrollment="110">
      <Title>Structured Probabilistic Models: Principles and Techniques</Title>
      <Description>Using probabilistic modeling languages to represent complex domains.</Description>
      <Instructors>
        <Professor>
          <First_Name>Daphne</First_Name>
          <Last_Name>Koller</Last_Name>    
        </Professor>
      </Instructors>
    </Course>

    <Course Number="CS229" Enrollment="320">
      <Title>Machine Learning</Title>
      <Description>A broad introduction to machine learning and statistical pattern recognition.</Description>
      <Instructors>
        <Professor>
          <First_Name>Andrew</First_Name>
          <Last_Name>Ng</Last_Name>    
        </Professor>
      </Instructors>
    </Course>

  </Department>

  <Department Code="EE">

    <Title>Electrical Engineering</Title>

    <Chair>
      <Professor>
        <First_Name>Mark</First_Name>
        <Middle_Initial>A.</Middle_Initial>
        <Last_Name>Horowitz</Last_Name>
      </Professor>    
    </Chair>

    <Course Number="EE108A">
      <Title>Digital Systems I</Title>
      <Description>Digital circuit, logic, and system design.</Description>
      <Instructors>
        <Professor>
          <First_Name>Subhasish</First_Name>
          <Last_Name>Mitra</Last_Name>
        </Professor>
      </Instructors>
    </Course>

    <Course Number="EE108B">
      <Title>Digital Systems II</Title>
      <Description>The design of processor-based digital systems.</Description>
      <Instructors>
        <Professor>
          <First_Name>William</First_Name>
          <Middle_Initial>J.</Middle_Initial>
          <Last_Name>Dally</Last_Name>
        </Professor>      
        <Professor>
          <First_Name>Oyekunle</First_Name>
          <Last_Name>Olukotun</Last_Name>
        </Professor>
      </Instructors>
      <Prerequisites>
        <Prereq>EE108A</Prereq>
        <Prereq>CS106B</Prereq>
      </Prerequisites>
    </Course>    

  </Department>

  <Department Code="LING">

    <Title>Linguistics</Title>

    <Chair>    
      <Professor>
        <First_Name>Beth</First_Name>
        <Last_Name>Levin</Last_Name>    
      </Professor>
    </Chair>

    <Course Number="LING180" Enrollment="60">
      <Title>From Languages to Information</Title>
      <Description>Natural language processing. Cross-listed as CS124.</Description>
      <Instructors>
        <Professor>
          <First_Name>Dan</First_Name>
          <Last_Name>Jurafsky</Last_Name>    
        </Professor>
      </Instructors>
      <Prerequisites>
        <Prereq>CS107</Prereq>
        <Prereq>CS109</Prereq>
      </Prerequisites>   
    </Course>
  </Department>
</Course_Catalog>
```

Comment: Post up your XML files and your DTD, otherwise it's just going to be complete guesswork.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a 'lint.xml' file. Open it and delete the ignore tag containing what you want to undo. If not, ignore this.

Comment: I am a beginner please describe in details how to do it.